# Blur event: do not blur if click occurs within element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks as follows, visually.

[image: Basic Color Picker Component]

[Here is a simplified codepen recreation](http://codepen.io/AlexFrazer/pen/VKAqRA?editors=0110).

The main problem comes in here:

```
<div className={styles.colorPicker}>
  <input
    readOnly
    type="text"
    value={color}
    onFocus={this.showColorPalette}
    onBlur={this.hideColorPalette}
  />
  <Palette
    color={color}
    onSelect={this.selectColor}
  />
</div>
```

The intended behavior is that, when they blur the component, the color palette should hide. **however**, if they clicked on something in the color palette, it should not hide the palette.

Because clicking on the color palette will blur the input, it will hide the palette. I can't find a way to reconcile the palette's `onClick` method with the input's `onBlur` method in such a way that one overrides the other.

Is there a way to do this in react?

Comment: my first idea is to implement react component that fires event when user clicks outside, here you have airbnb [implementation](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/src/components/OutsideClickHandler.jsx). Then you can use it in the following way `<OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={hideColorPallete}> <ColorPallete open={showPicker}/> <OutsideClickHandler/>`

Comment: that is helpful, but what happens if they press `tab` to move to the next input field?

Comment: next input should call a `hideColorPallete` on onfocus event

Answer (score 6):

just tried something using `onMouseEnter` and `onMousLeave` to conditionally trigger `blur()`. By this the color pallette will be visible for picking color and will be blurred when the color is picked or click outside the input box.

Check the updatde pen

http://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/EgoaGK?editors=0110

Comment: That works exactly as expected! Thank you for the answer

Comment: @corvid Glad it helped. Consider up voting and accepting the answer